# Write 3 instructions in 1 in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

The following instructions are given:

```
add bx, 3 or 4
mov ax, si
add bx,ax
```

How can you write this by using only one instruction?

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, you can't. There is no instruction that will do two separate calculations and put two unrelated values in the `ax` and `bx` registers.

If it's only getting the value into `bx` that is interesting, then it's possible. You can use the `lea` instruction to do the calculation in the form of a memory address, and store the value in `bx`:

```
lea bx, [bx + si + (3 or 4)]
```